# MYSQL REGEX in Select query

Tags: mysql, regex, syntax, mysql-8.0

Need a Regex solution to select only a pattern of string from a column.

Data looks like this:

```
Column1
Data Type = String 

Data = 
"130 - 66||109,118 - 3||102 - 18||109,118 - 2||109,116,149 - 14||141 - 8||130 - 31||102 - 12"
```

Expected Result

```
66, 3, 18, 2, 14, 8, 31, 12
```

Tried REgex - `"\-(...*?)\W"` but it doesn't work.

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Comment: SELECT VERSION() = 8.0.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this

```
SELECT REPLACE(REGEXP_REPLACE('130 - 66||109,118 - 3||102 - 18||109,118 - 2||109,116,149 - 14||141 - 8||130 - 31||102 - 12',
                                     '(([,0-9]+) - )', ''),'||',',');
```

and result

```
66,3,18,2,14,8,31,12
```

[Referance](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-regular-expressions-regexp/)

Comment: This works Ferhat, what if i need the values before -
like 130, 109,118,102,109,118,109,116,149,141,130,102

Comment: I am not good the regular expresision but when i need regex I use it this site https://regex101.com/ and try it

Comment: Just use this regex "(- [0-9]+)" finding others

Comment: Got it , Thanks Ferhat

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `REGEXP` returns a boolean, not a string.

excerpt from MySQL Reference Manual:

> Returns `1` if the string `expr` matches the regular expression specified by the pattern `pat`, `0` otherwise. If `expr` or `pat` is `NULL`, the return value is `NULL`.

Maybe we want to use MySQL `REGEXP_REPLACE` function ?

Reference:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#operator_regexp

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace

Comment: Thanks Spencer, 
Tried but it is just removing the '-' sign 
select REGEXP_REPLACE('130 - 66||109,118 - 3||102 - 18||109,118 - 2||109,116,149 - 14||141 - 8||130 - 31||102 - 12', '-','');

Output - 130  66||109,118  3||102  18||109,118  2||109,116,149  14||141  8||130  31||102  12